# Est-ce que « par solidarité pour » est d’usage?

Tags: locutions, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Il agit ainsi par solidarité pour Alain, qui se donne corps et âme à cette plateforme de questions et de réponse.

Contexte:

Alain est un contributeur qui déploie beaucoup d’efforts à Reddit, mais il est souvent l’objet d’attaques de la part d’autres contributeurs car ses réponses, nombreuses, renferment parfois des erreurs. La philosophie d’Alain est de privilégier la quantité sur la qualité afin de rejoindre et d’aider le plus grand nombre. C’est pourquoi il rédige ses réponses à la hâte, ce qui le conduit parfois à se tromper et à faire l’objet de commentaires qui portent atteinte à son mérite. D’autres contributeurs, souvent il s’agit d’éditeurs, plutôt que de lui laisser des commentaires, s’acharnent sur lui en proposant sans cesse des modifications à ses réponses et signalent ces dernières à la modération. Mathieu, un autre contributeur de Reddit, par solidarité pour Alain, n’apporte plus de modification à ses réponses quand elles font l’objet de révisions, prétextant que l’erreur est humaine, que l’humain est faillible, qu’il est important de souligner ce fait et renchérissant que d’autres proposeront des réponses correctes et pertinentes sur lesquelles le demandeur pourra jeter son dévolu.

Comment: Je suis solidaire ***avec** mes amis* ***pour** défendre une cause*.

Comment: @Personne C'est vrai, mais ce n'est pas la même construction. *Je suis solidaire pour mes amis* ne s'entend pas mais *Par solidarité pour [...]* est courant.

Comment: @jlliagre … *avec* et *pour* sont liés à la cible de l'action ou au contexte, quelle que soit la construction : — « … un autre contributeur de Reddit, par solidarité ***pour*** Alain, … » un contributeur aide/défend un collègue contre l'adversité (l'exemple de ta réponse). — « … un autre contributeur de Reddit, par solidarité ***avec*** Alain, … » un contributeur aide/défend l'action/la cause dans laquelle Alain est engagé. NB : *Envers* est synonyme et de *pour* et de *avec* selon le Robert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On dit plus souvent « par solidarité **avec** » mais « par solidarité **pour** », ainsi que « par solidarité **envers** » (plus soutenu) se rencontrent aussi, avec le même sens. Tous sont parfaitement idiomatiques.

> *ERT: Télé Bruxelles change de logo **par solidarité pour** la télévision publique grecque*, [Le Huffington Post, 2013](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2013/06/12/ert-tele-bruxelles-solidarite-television-publique_n_3427475.html)

[image]

Source: [Sequoia - Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/SequoiaBio/photos/a.121998231193749/3633267756733428/?type=3)

Answer (score 1):

On trouve que cette préposition a été utilisée, comme  le montrent ce [bigram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=par+solidarit%C3%A9+pour%2Cpar+solidarit%C3%A9+avec&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0) ainsi qu'un examen de la page « [solidarité pour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22par%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) », celui-ci mettant en évidence que le syntagme prépositionnel « pour … » fait bien partie du groupe nominal qui a pour noyau le mot « solidarité ». Les faits que
1° que le bigram montre une fréquence très supérieure de l'utilisation de « avec »
2° que parmi les exemples de la page « [solidarité avec](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22par%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » les cas où la partie « avec … » ne fait pas partie du groupe nominal sont pratiquement inexistants, et
3° que dans la page « solidarité pour » il y a quelques cas où le groupe prépositionnel ne fait pas  partie du groupe nominal dont le noyau est « solidarité,
montrent que la fréquence d'utilisation de « pour » en rapport avec l'usage qui nous concerne est en réalité très faible en comparaison de celle d'« avec » ; cela signifie que pour l'usage concerné le graphe pour « avec » est à peu près celui qui est montré ci-dessous (courbe rouge) et celui pour « pour » est légèremet  plus bas que la courbe bleue.

[image]

En conclusion, on pourrait dire que « pour » ne serait pas très idiomatique et qu'il serait préférable d'utiliser « avec », mais il y a une question de sens : il en existe deux qui pourraient convenir;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/solidarit%C3%A9)) Responsabilité mutuelle qui s'établit entre les membres d'un groupe social.

> Devoir moral, résultant de la prise de conscience de l'interdépendance sociale étroite existant entre les hommes ou dans des groupes humains, et qui incite les hommes à s'unir, à se porter entraide et assistance réciproque et à coopérer entre eux, en tant que membres d'un même corps social. Synon fraternité.

Comme le sens à donner à ce mot semble être  le second, alors « pour » conviendrait mieux (ou « envers »), mais il n'est pas certain que le sens ne sois pas le premier.

Comment: Je suis très surpris pas ton interprétation des NGrams de *par solidarité pour*. Il y a très peu de faux positifs. *Pas solidarité pour xxx* est tout à fait idiomatique.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai, je viens de vérifier, en effet il y en a peu ; je corrige.

Comment: Ta réponse continue à soutenir que *par solidarité pour* n'est pas très idiomatique, ce que contredisent plusieurs centaines d'ouvrages imprimés et d'innombrables pages web.

Comment: @jlliagre J''ai changé le mode du verbe : conditionnel au lieu du présent ; alors, non, je ne soutiens pas ça, vraiment … c'est seulement une apparence, avant de considérer que plusieurs sens sont possible et que c'est le second qui est le bon (ou bien s'agit-il du premier ?) ; à mon avis ce ne serait pas très logique s'il s'agissait du premier sens parce qu'il est fondé sur une notion de mutualité, pour laquelle « avec » seul semble convenir .

Comment: Ok, mais tu as oublié un indicatif ici: *En conclusion, on **peut** dire que « pour » n'est pas très idiomatique*.

Answer (score 0):

Cette réponse est une réécriture en CW d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48474) (de LPH), respectant l'outil de mise en page et se voulant claire, pertinente et exacte.

---

On trouve aussi l'emploi de la préposition « pour », comme le montrent ce [bigram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=par%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0) ainsi qu'un examen des résultats de « [solidarité pour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22par%20solidarit%C3%A9%20pour%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » (comparer avec « [solidarité avec](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22par%20solidarit%C3%A9%20avec%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) »), où l'on voit que le syntagme prépositionnel « pour... » fait bien partie du groupe nominal qui a pour noyau le mot « solidarité ».

[image]
Ce que l'on peut dire, c'est que l'emploi avec « pour » est beaucoup moins fréquent (à peu près 10 fois moins que « avec »), mais il y a une question de sens. Il en existe deux qui pourraient convenir :

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/solidarit%C3%A9)) Responsabilité mutuelle qui s'établit entre les membres d'un groupe social.

> Devoir moral, résultant de la prise de conscience de l'interdépendance sociale étroite existant entre les hommes ou dans des groupes humains, et qui incite les hommes à s'unir, à se porter entraide et assistance réciproque et à coopérer entre eux, en tant que membres d'un même corps social. Synon fraternité.

Comme le sens à donner à ce mot semble être le second, alors « pour » conviendrait mieux il me semble (ou « envers »), mais il n'est pas certain que le sens ne soit pas le premier.